# Configure Terraform map(object{}) variables where some key: values are sensitive and others have regex validation. For_each can't handle it

Tags: terraform, cisco

I use a lot of resource blocks with `for_each` that call variables of type `map(object({}))`.

I need to both mark some values `sensitive = true` (i.e. password) AND also regex-validate other values. I've referenced [Terraform - Adding Validation for type = map(object()) in variables.tf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191534/terraform-adding-validation-for-type-mapobject-in-variables-tf) without recourse.

If I use these two functions in my variable declarations, I get "Error: Invalid for_each argument" with verbose explanation:

> *Sensitive values, or values derived from sensitive values, cannot be used as for_each arguments. If used, the sensitive value could be exposed as a resource instance key.*

My code builds Cisco ACI [network] configuration (if that's relevant). What are some other ways I could accomplish these requirements, since for_each doesn't allow it?

**main.tf**

```
resource "aci_vmm_credential" "vmmcredLocalName" {
  for_each = var.vmmacc_map
    vmm_domain_dn  = aci_vmm_domain.vmmdomainLocalName[each.key].id
    name  = each.value.name
    annotation = "orchestrator:terraform"
    pwd = each.value.password
    usr = each.value.username
}
```

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "vmmacc_map" {
  type = map(object( {
    name         = string
    password     = string
    username     = string  
  }))
  sensitive = true
  validation {
    condition = (
      can(regexall("
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
vmmacc_map = {
    "ACI_Non_Prod_VDSwitch-mktest" = {
        name           = "Non_Prod_Creds-mktest"
        username       = "svc_aci_vmm-mktest"
        password       = "password"
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not believe you can denote part of a declared variable as `sensitive`. For the validation part, you can code a `for` expression to dynamically validate your `map(object))`.

Comment: (I find `can(regexall("` to look funny for incompleteness.)